# Bind a directive scope property to a string

Tags: angularjs

HTML code:

```
<ul  drag-drop  idProperty="today" >
  <li  draggable="true" ng-repeat="option in options track by $index" >
       {{option.plan_option_id}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

dragDrop is a custom directive:

```
module.directive('dragDrop',  function() {
  return {      
    scope: {
      idProperty:'@'
    },
     ...
  }
});
```

I want for the idProperty to get just a string value (e.g. Tuesday) **without being connected to the $scope** (e.g. $scope.today='Tuesday'). Is there anyway to bind idProperty **directly** in HTML with a string value? Something like that: `idProperty="'Tuesday'"`

Comment: Use `id-property="today"` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `id-property="today"` instead to make this work.

To get it without using the `scope` of the directive, you can just read the directive's attributes:

```
module.directive('dragDrop',  function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var idProperty = attrs.idProperty;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close.

You have this line:

```
<ul  drag-drop  idProperty="today" >
```

which should be

```
<ul  drag-drop  id-property="today" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably should look like this

```
 <ul  drag-drop  id-property="today" >
 <li  draggable="true" ng-repeat="option in options track by $index" >
   {{option.plan_option_id}}
</li>
```

```
module.directive('dragDrop',  function() {
return {      
 scope: {
   idProperty:'@'
 },
 link: function(scope,elem, attrs, ctrl){
        var idProperty = null;
        attrs.$observe('idProperty', function(val){
           var idProperty = val
        })
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use Directive in your html then it must be used be use like this

```
ngRepeat directive 
in html - > ng-repeat


your directive which you have made
idProperty
in html -> id-property
```

because every capital character should be replaced with **<-(smallcharacter)**>
so use

```
  <ul drag-drop id-property="today">
```

Read this documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive